# ruby, why using a module inside a module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Trying to perform RemoteAuthetication with devise, i ran into an example (almost an official one, since devise wiki is limited to refer to [this document](http://4trabes.com/2012/10/31/remote-authentication-with-devise/)).

All the classes that actually implement the authentication algorithm are "double" enclosed into either Devise, Models or Devise, Strategies. 
Here is the Devise, Models example:

```
module Devise
  module Models
    module RemoteAuthenticatable

      extend ActiveSupport::Concern

      def remote_authentication(authentication_hash)
        # Your logic to authenticate with the external webservice
      end

    end
  end
end
```

First question: how can you explain to a ruby newbie (as I am), maybe coming from another language, such as java, what is the rationale of this sort of namespace? 
 
While namespaces in different flavours are common among programming languages, this particular way of using them is somewhat new to me. 
In other languages one wouldn't use the very same namespace of the thirdy party library (such as devise in this case) **even when implementing interfaces or extending classes provided by it**.

But here we see that devise itself, in its bits, defines a

```
module Devise
  module Models
     module Authenticatable
     extend ActiveSupport::Concern
     ...
  end
end
```

Second question: here the module Authenticatable seems to extend another module. I found lots of docs about classes including or extending other modules, but not modules extending other modules. What is the purpose of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re: Question 1

The namespacing provides organization. Devise is made up of a few parts that integrate into your application eg. Models, Controllers, Authentication logic, etc...

The reason one would use the same namespacing can be

1. to keep that same organizational structure.
2. to add/edit the original modules and/or classes. Ruby allows one to reopen a class or module and override or add additional logic. So one doesn't have to extend/include a class/module to patch in there own code.

However, you do want to take care when reopening a class/module you don't own.

---

Re: Question 2

Modules are very similar to Class (*Class actually is a child of Module, which then goes up the chain to Object then BasicObject*), with the exception they can't be *Instantiated*. But, they can have methods, variables and all that jazz and act as a singular object. So modules can naturally include and extend other modules to gain the logic to use within the module that is doing the including or extending.

---

[Ruby Class Docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Class.html), 
[Ruby Module Docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Module.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the object model, Ruby modules get appended to the ancestors chain in classes. So:

```
Module B; end
class A
  include B
end
A.ancestors # => A, B, etc.
```

Now when B extends another module:

```
Module C
  def a_module_method; end
end
Module B; extend C; end
```

Then Ruby adds `a_module_method` to the class methods in the ancestors chain. So you can do:

```
A.a_module_method
```

So it is a different way to give you access to module methods. A good rationale for this is to isolate instance methods from class methods.